# Why isn't my simple image drawing using Graphics.drawImage?

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles, drawimage

The image just won't appear. I've tried resizing the rectangle size. My image is 24 by 24 pixels. fillRectangle() on the canvas has worked in this same way, so why does switching to drawImage() not work?

```
    int xCoord = object.X_COORD;
    int yCoord = object.Y_COORD;

    Point points = new Point(xCoord, yCoord);
    var lcDevicePoint = inProjection.MapToSurface.ToPoint(points);

    var lcRectangle = new Rectangle(lcDevicePoint, new Size(1000, 1000));

    Image newImage = Image.FromFile("[imagepath].png");

    inGraphics.DrawImage(newImage, lcRectangle, lcRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Comment: Does it compile? (I'm talking about a variable named `object`). Any reason you don't simply do `inGraphics.DrawImage(newImage, lcRectangle)`? Second Rectangle parameter is **source** rectangle but your image is 24x24 so I guess `lcDevicePoint` has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong overload of the `DrawImage` method. Try it like this:

```
inGraphics.DrawImage(newImage, lcRectangle);
```

Additionally check that your `Image` object is initialised correctly.

Comment: That did it! So many overloads for this method gets a little confusing. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also, when drawing my image after the first time, the old one doesn't disappear. How is this properly done?

Comment: This depends on what `inGraphics` is. If it is a `PictureBox` just add `inGraphics.Image = null;` before the call to `DrawImage`.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your code snippet as follows to ensure that you've correctly specified the [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx) method's parameters and avoided unnecessary image resizing:

```
Image newImage = Image.FromFile("[imagepath].png");
Size newImageSize = newImage.Size;
var lcRectangle = new Rectangle(lcDevicePoint, newImageSize );
inGraphics.DrawImage(newImage, lcRectangle);
```